$|v+w|^2+|v-w|^2 = 2(|v|^2+|w|^2)$ then the vector space has a Euclidean norm
From the book 'a course in metric geometry' exercise 1.2.20 the hard way : 
if $|v+w|^2+|v-w|^2 = 2(|v|^2+|w|^2)$ for every $v,w \in V $ then the norm |.| on vector space $V$ is Euclidean. 
I have tried to use the quadratic form and inserting $v+w$ and such stuff in it but got no result.

If by "Euclidean" you mean that the norm is induced from an inner product on $V$, then it's explained here.
If the norm $ \lVert \cdot \rVert $ is induced from an inner product $ \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle $, then we have:
$$ \lVert v+w \rVert^2 = \langle v+w, v+w \rangle = \lVert v \rVert^2 + \lVert w \rVert^2 + 2\mathrm{Re} \langle v, w \rangle $$
Suppose $V$ is a real vector space, then we get:
$$ \langle v, w \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \left( \lVert v+w \rVert^2 -\lVert v \rVert^2 -\lVert w \rVert^2 \right) $$
So for any norm, we have a candidate for an inner product that should induce it. It is clearly symmetric, but for now linearity in the first argument is not obvious. Note that we do get positive-definiteness:
$$ \langle v, v \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \left(  \lVert v+v \rVert^2 -\lVert v \rVert^2 -\lVert v \rVert^2 \right) = 2\lVert v \rVert^2 -\lVert v \rVert^2 = \lVert v \rVert^2  $$
which is always nonnegative, and vanishes iff $v=0$. Now, let's assume the parallelogram law holds; then:
$$ \langle v, w \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \lVert v+w \rVert^2 -\frac{\lVert v+w \rVert^2+\lVert v-w \rVert^2}{4} = \frac{1}{4} \left( \lVert v+w \rVert^2 -\lVert v-w \rVert^2 \right) $$
Linearity would follow from the properties $ \langle \alpha v, w \rangle = \alpha \langle v, w \rangle $ and $ \langle x+y, w \rangle = \langle x, w \rangle + \langle y, w \rangle $. The argument here becomes slightly convoluted, but it's explained fairly well in the Wikipedia page I linked to before.

I just don't understand why any positive-definite, real-valued,
-bilinear form satisfies the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality as in the proof of the inequality the fraction may be irrational because $v\neq 0$ is arbitrary. (this is for (4) in the link you gave me)
